# typescript，check the type of object, typeof get compile error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeguards

with this code

```js
export default class App {
  el: HTMLElement;
  constructor(el: string | HTMLElement) {
    if (typeof el === "string") {
      this.el = document.getElementById(el);
    }
    if (typeof el === typeof this.el) {
      this.el = el;
    }
  }
}
```

get compile error info:
Type 'string | HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2322)

changed code like as follow ,will get no error info:

```js
export default class App {
  el: HTMLElement;
  constructor(el: string | HTMLElement) {
    if (typeof el === "string") {
      this.el = document.getElementById(el);
    }
    if (el instanceof HTMLElement) {
      this.el = el;
    }
  }
}
```

i'm confused, they should both get error or  both get worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear, the `typeof el` returns one of `"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"` type at runtime.

At TS compiler time, `typeof` becomes a type guard, TS will narrow the type to `string | HTMLElement`.
But the instance props `this.el` is just `HTMLElement`.

You should narrow the type of `el` to `HTMLElement`, so you need to check it's not `string` type.

> `instanceof` type guards are a way of narrowing types using their constructor function.

`el instanceof HTMLElement` statement will narrow the type of `el` to `HTMLElement` which can be assigned to `this.el`.

```
class App {
    el: HTMLElement | null = null;
    constructor(el: string | HTMLElement) {
        if (typeof el === "string") {
            this.el = document.getElementById(el);
        }
        if (typeof el === typeof this.el && typeof el !== 'string') {
            this.el = el;
        }
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1&module=6#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAO9oG8BQ0PQKYgFzQAkAVAWQBkBRELAWywDsAXaAH2noFcQRoBedriADc6TMAD29CIwBOHYI3EyAFDnzSZAS3oBzVoVKVqdJgEoUozJk0AzaMsYBPeFnF2cfXvwBEG7Tu9zNCsQzEYAC00IADoPfgATcWAOE0ZonSxGKloGRgAhRwBJeNUQUxFQjABfSxDbeycXN2weL35G1zsIqNieADI+6A7mjwBCL2gAcj9dSaDayqHImLiWisqaqxqa1FBIGAR4AEYLDDUDcmzU-U5uPgFudYkpWXlFFXOZvTZiS+Nc+ZWeoOZydFqeHxfQKnELdFataCJZKpdKZK65ArFUrlWqbax2UrQbTSMD0YBg35GHJmGFWOG9e44dbVUTbIA)

Comment: thanks ,  
i  should read the [advanced-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` can return only `undefined`, `null`, `boolean`, `number`, `bigint`, `string`, `symbol`, `function`, and `object`.

You can see more detail in this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between typescript's `typeof` and javascript's `typeof`. According to this [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html), when you use `typeof` in an expression context, you are actually using the javascript one. Thus:

```
if (typeof el === typeof this.el) {
  this.el = el;
}
```

you end up checking two entities both having the type `"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"`.
To help typescript infer the type correctly, you must use an explicit type in your condition:

```
if (typeof el === 'object') {
  this.el = el;
}
```

But in your case, the best way is to use an `else` statement:

```
if (typeof el === 'string') {
  this.el = document.getElementById(el);
} else {
  this.el = el;
}
```

Comment: yea,i do used the if...else structure ,it do worked,but i thought may be el will be expand to more type someday, so made an attempt to check the type of el

Comment: In this case, the best way is to use `instanceof` for build-in and custom types, and `typeof el` with explicit type for natives.

Comment: The problem with the "typeof el === typeof this.el && typeof el !== 'string'" solution is that, one, the `typeof el === typeof this.el` part is useless, and two, `typeof el !== 'string` is just the equivalent of an `else` statement.